# Changing a sound to match different multiples

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've made myself a very basic app which counts your taps and gives a nice "ping" for every tap. What I would like help with is making it so at certain landmarks you get a different sound, kind of like a well-done for the user. What should I put so that for every multiple of 100 it gives off a different sound from usual?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var background1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

var tapSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("schwing", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

 var playerScoreTotal = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: tapSound, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func screenTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    audioPlayer.play()


        playerScoreTotal += 1
    self.counterLabel.text = String(playerScoreTotal)
 self.counterLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to check if `playerScoreTotal` is a multiple of 100 ?

Comment: I don't know how to make it so that each multiple of 100 gives off a different should clip than usual @MartinR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second audioplayer with a different sound.

Then you can add this check to your function:

```
if ((playerScoreTotal % 100) != 0){
//Play the original sound
}
else{
//Play the **second** sound, do other stuff
}
//Do your other updates here
```